# Authentication SPI for keycloak

Tags: maven, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have referred to the [Keycloak Auth SPI documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi) at and implemented another SPI. I have referred to example `authenticator-required-action-example`. It's working fine when I am following instructions from `README.md` file. However, I want to push this implementation to production and I want to package this SPI as part of distribution directory.

The instructions mentioned in README states that you need to run `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` command to embedd this SPI into running keycloak instance. During development we can do this but on production, what are the ways to embed this as part of the distribution so that I need not run this maven command.

Comment: Hi Krishna Kuntala, Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, package your authenticator as a jar-file.

Then, you can add it with `jboss-cli`.

Navigate to your keycloak installation, and the `bin`-folder. There, you should have a file named `jboss-cli.sh`.

Run the following command:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --command='deploy <path to deployable jar> --name=<name your deploayable>'
```